# UIPopoverController wrong UITextField height in iOS 8

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios8, xamarin, uipopovercontroller

In my app I use a `UIPopoverController` with an embedded `UINaviagtionController` to show a single line UITextField to enter a number. This kind of input was working up to iOS 7.1. Since iOS 8.0 the size of the UITextField is wrong. I tried out to change the AutoresizingMask, Frame, EdgesForExtendedLayout, ... but nothing is working.

As you can see in the screenshots bellow, there is a strange behaviour.

A sample project for Xamarin.iOS is available: http://www.danflash.com/files/dev/PopoverTest.zip

[image: iOS 7]
[image: iOS 8]

Comment: How about using auto layout constraints?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with auto layout constraints. All my layouts are written in code instead of using the storyboard designer. The used helper class is widely used in different apps and hundreds of times. I want to avoid a big impact by changing to auto layout constraints. Do you have a sample how to change my current code to do that?

Comment: You can build your layout with constraints from code, not necessarily from IB. I don't think you will be able to avoid auto layout in the future, that's the way Apple wants you to do it.

Comment: Take a look at this nice sample framework presented at WWDC 2014: https://github.com/zwaldowski/AAPLAdvancedCollectionView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue. I had to set `contentViewController.EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;` within the method:

`public static PopoverInputController GetPopoverController(...)`

It seems that Apple did some more changes to the UI regarding the layout stuff as expected.